# Should I release objects added to a dictionary initialized from a file?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am loading a dictionary from a .plist like this:

```
switches = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:
                    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Switches" ofType:@"plist"]];
[switches retain];
```

And now I need to add a new entry (which is another dictionary) to it. To create the dictionary and add it I do this:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *newObject = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [switches setObject:newObject forKey:@"MyNewObject"];
```

Do I have to release `newObject`? I mean, I think that `switches` will take care of it anyway, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should release newObject after adding it to your dictionary. As the dictionary will add +1 to the retain count and as you used "alloc" as part of the initialisation of the object you already have a retain count of 1.

```
NSMutableDictionary *newObject = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [switches setObject:newObject forKey:@"MyNewObject"];
[newObject release];
```

or

```
NSMutableDictionary *newObject = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]autorelease];
    [switches setObject:newObject forKey:@"MyNewObject"];
```

or

```
NSMutableDictionary *newObject = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [switches setObject:newObject forKey:@"MyNewObject"];
```

would also be acceptable

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries retain the objects that you put into them (all cocoa collections do that), so you do need to release `newObject`.

Alternatively you could create it as an autoreleased object, like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newObject = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

This way you would not need to release `newObject` explicitly.